# Getting error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY) when migrating from MS Access 2013 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ms-sql, microsoft-access-2013

OK.... I've checked and rechecked Google, StackFault, Experts-Exchange, etc... for a resolution on this error and they all say to register the `DAO360.DLL` and add its path to the environment settings. I've done that several times and I still get the following error:

> Access Object Collector error: Database
>   Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao._DBEngine'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00000021-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
>   An error occurred while loading database content.

I'm not using compression and this is a clean install of Windows 7 Enterprise x64, Office 2013 Pro Plus x64 and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

I am migrating from an 2013 .accdb to SQL 2014. I have tried previous versions as well. And I am using the migration wizard from SSMA 6.0.

What am I missing, overlooking, needing to do, etc...?

Comment: http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Comment: Was the Access DB created in the 64-bit Access version, or 32-bit?

Comment: The file was created in access x64.